# cannot find -lC:\SQLAPI\lib\sqlapi.lib in omnet++ IDE

Tags: c++, sql-server, omnet++, sqlapi++

I am running my simple C++ program in OMNET ++ IDE
My code is as follows

```
**#include <stdio.h>  // for printf
#include <string.h>
#include <SQLAPI.h> // main SQLAPI++ header
//#include <asaAPI.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SAConnection con;
    con.setOption( "UseAPI" ) = "DB-Library";
    con.setClient( SA_SQLServer_Client );
    try
    {

                con.Connect(
                "paper2"
                "NADRA",
                "",
                SA_SQLServer_Client);

        printf("We are connected!\n");

        // Disconnect is optional
        // autodisconnect will occur in destructor if needed
        //con.Disconnect();

        printf("We are disconnected!\n");
    }
    catch(SAException &x)
    {
        // SAConnection::Rollback()
        // can also throw an exception
        // (if a network error for example),
        // we will be ready
        try
        {
            // on error rollback changes
            //con.Rollback();
        }
        catch(SAException &)
        {
        }
        // print error message
        printf("%s\n", (const char*)x.ErrText());
    }

    return 0;
}**
```

I have already linked all the files but the error that i am getting is as follow

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\SQLAPI\lib\sqlapi.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where as the file `sqlapi.lib` is in the same folder but linker is not able to find it. Can someone tells me about the issue that why compiler is not able to link it .I am using `MINGW` as a C++ compiler. The screen shot is attached by with the question about the linked files[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I8lB.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `-l`, then it should be followed by the library name only, so something like:

```
-lsqlapi
```

If you want to specify a search path, then:

```
-lsqlapi -LC:\SQLAPI\lib\
```

(Usually the path is in Linux mode, so `C:/SQLAPI/lib though).

Then if this doesn't work, you can always force the library to be linked by just using it as another object:

```
C:/SQLAPI/lib/sqlapi.lib
```

Note though that gcc doesn't link against Visual Studio static libraries, which `sqlapi` might (because of the extension being `.lib` and not `.a`, but then this may be the export library for a `dll`).

Comment: With your suggestions it is still not working. It is givng the error c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l-lsqlapi

Comment: I never said to write `-l-lsqlapi`. The commad is `-lsqlapi`. If omnet adds -l, then just remove it.

Comment: I dont know how i can remove -1 ,it is automatically added by omnet compiler, I am only writing the simple command  "C:\SQLAPI\lib\sqlapi.lib" as you can also see in my attached screenshot.

Comment: Don't write the full path, just put the name pf the library, without .lib, and the path to the library path.